# Как поменять кодировку строки?

Tags: android, кодировка, java, utf-8

Есть у меня строка, значение которой я получаю из JSON файла

```
final String transname=jsonObj.getString("name");
```

Объект "name" в JSON файле может содержать как латиницу, так и кириллицу, но кириллица отображается как ромб с вопросом. Я так понимаю, используется кодировка "cp1251", а нужно "UTF-8". Как изменить кодировку?

P.S. Android разработка.
Код пирсинга:

```
final AssetManager manager = getAssets();
String myjsonstring;

// Reading text file from assets folder
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
"bipolar.txt")));
String temp;
while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
sb.append(temp);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
try {
br.close(); // stop reading
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

myjsonstring = sb.toString();

// Try to parse JSON
try {
// Creating JSONObject from String
JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);

// Creating JSONArray from JSONObject
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("polar");

// JSONArray has four JSONObject
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

// Creating JSONObject from JSONArray
JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

// Getting data from individual JSONObject
final String oldtransname=jsonObj.getString("name");}}
```

Comment: код *п**и**рсинга* это круто...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("bipolar.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Не получается

Comment: В какой кодировке текстовый файл?

Comment: Спасибо всем большое, поменял кодировку файла и вставил код выше.